# MiniFilter Driver - The right implementation and the Microsoft signature

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, malware-detection, minifilter

I am working on malware analysis. I use a mini-filter driver to intercept file system access. Then I apply algorithms to detect malicious activity.
My questions:
It know that the driver will need a signature by Microsoft for a public release.
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/attestation-signing-a-kernel-driver-for-public-release

Is it authorized to implement the algorithms as AI in kernel space, or I must implement them in userspace? What is recommended concerning Microsoft, the right architecture, and security?

Comment: You don't have access to Windows kernel space, you can listen, take actions but it's in userspace (usually as a service running in the background). If you ment a driver which has algorithms init, then you wont receive a public release cause it will degregate systems stability.

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement a Windows kernel driver, you can do whatever you want. Not only algorithms, we ever ported OpenSSL, SQLite and other open source projects (of course in C and C++) to our Windows kernel drivers. It's not something mission impossible. Just you need to know how and limitations with work-around.

The idea of driver signing from MS is to avoid rogue driver developers to run malware in kernel. This was the biggest issue for 32 bit Windows for very long time, since in kernel you are not only able to implement something but you can also abuse anything, including kernel variable, file system data, registry and you can even hook to any code you want (if system protection is not running). However, such certificate is also not perfect. Years ago hackers stole certificates from companies (RealTek, if I recall it correctly) and signed their malware drivers.